# javascript runs for two times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4.2, turbolinks

I'm adding form element dynamically using jquery, the js code is as:-

```
$(document).on('ready page:change page:load', function(){
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_lp_button").on('click', function(){
    var elem = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'><input type='text' name='language_pack[mappings[" + i + "][key]]' class='form-control' placeholder='Key' /></div><div class='col-md-6'><input type='text' name='language_pack[mappings[" + i + "][value]]' class='form-control' placeholder='Value' /></div></div>";
    $('#key_val').append(elem);
    i = i + 1;
  });
});
```

and the html.erb code is as:-

```
<%= form_for(@language_pack) do |f| %>
  <%= error_messages(@language_pack) %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label 'language name and code', class: 'control-label required' %>
    <%= f.select(:lang_name, country_locale.to_a.collect { |v| ["#{v[0].capitalize} (#{v[1]})", v[0].capitalize] }, { prompt: 'Select' }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :mappings, class: "control-label" %>
    <div id='key_val'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= text_field_tag "language_pack[mappings[0][key]]", nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Key" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= text_field_tag "language_pack[mappings[0][value]]", nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Value" %><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='add_lp_button' class='btn btn-raised btn-primary pull-right'>Add</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-raised btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, the problem is that, when I click the "ADD" button then js gets executed for two times means 2 * 2 = 4, form elements get appended. What's the issue. Thankyou.

Comment: i don't think it will do so.. but try doing like adding onclick attribute to the anchor tag and give the method 'X' for eg., and put your appending stuff inside that method 'X'

Comment: @ABUdhay, Thanks for guidance. Actually solution provided worked well, but I would like  to know the reason that why js was being executed for two time.

Comment: may be because of event delegation..